# same on space but different in time complexity

Tags: complexity-theory

I had made the comparison in between 2 algorithms, A and B. I found that, the time complexity of these 2 algorithms is different, which are O(n^3) and O(n^4) respectively, but the space complexity of both A and B is same, which is O(n). Is that have probability?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is possible, yes. The time complexity and the space complexity are not necessarily related to each other.

As an example, think of various sorting algorithms, such as the ones in [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_sorting_algorithms#Comparison_of_algorithms) - as you see, both insertion sort and heapsort have a space-complexity (column *memory*) of O(1), while their time complexities are different.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Like the case I mentioned, does it means A is not good than B?

Comment: @user3398803: If both A and B have the same space-complexity, and the time complexity for A is O(n^3), while that for B is O(n^4), then A sounds *better* than B. However, please note that "the time-complexity" is sometimes not the decisive factor; for example, you should at least look at the complexities of the worst and the average cases and think about what the situation will usually be like. Also, there are other factors that sometimes warrant ignoring a somewhat worse complexity, for example in the case of sorting algorithms whether a sorting is stable.